# How to prove that the following is partial recursive?

Tags: computability, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

Let $g$ and $h$ be to two partial recursive functions and let us define the following function :

$f(x,y) =\left\{ 
\begin{array}{ll}
g(y) & \mbox{if} \ x=0,\\
f(x-1,h(x-1,y)) & \mbox{if} \ x>0.
\end{array}
\right.$

The goal is to show that the function $f$ is recursive (partial).

It is suggested to apply a fixed-point theorem and before to consider for all functions $\psi : \mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}$, the function :

$\Omega(x,y) =\left\{ 
\begin{array}{ll}
g(y) & \mbox{if} \ x=0,\\
\psi(x-1,h(x-1,y)) & \mbox{if} \ x>0.
\end{array}
\right.$

-The first idea could be to show that $\Omega= \psi$ only if $f = \psi$. As the function $\Omega$ is defined for all $\psi$, we can take $f=\psi$ and write : $\Omega(x,y) =\left\{ 
\begin{array}{ll}
g(y) & \mbox{if} \ x=0,\\
f(x-1,h(x-1,y)) & \mbox{if} \ x>0.
\end{array}
\right.$

Hence by definition of $f$, we can deduce that : $\Omega = f$. Then $\Omega = \psi$.

For the uniqueness of $f$, we can consider another function $f_1$ such that $f_1 = \psi$. Necessarily $\Omega=f_1$ and then $f_1=f$.

-The second idea as suggested is to apply a fixed-point theorem. I do not really know how to proceed. I imagine that $f$ is defined as the fixed-point of a set of equations...

Also the definition of $f$ could be a recursive one (we have cases, composition and predecessor) but the problem is that we do not know yet if $f$ or $\psi= \Omega$ are partial recursive functions.

I meet difficulties to make the link between the two hints.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Which operations do you know preserve (partial) recursiveness? You've mentioned fixed point operators, but what else? Are you allowed to use (un)bounded search? What book are you using? There's a lot of (equivalent) definitions in computability theory, and while this doesn't matter in our day-to-day lives, when we're first getting the subject off the ground, it matters quite a lot.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor We can define the class of partial recursive functions as the smallest class which contains : initial functions, composition, primitive recursion and $\mu$-recursion. With that you can obtain for instance that the predecessor function but also that the class is closed under boolean combinations, by fixed-point operators and definition by cases (not trivial).